# How to make normal arrays become a dimension array based on the first item?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, merge

Below are my arrays echoed inside a for-each loop.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2
)
Array 
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
)
```

I would like to group these arrays based on the value of the first item (index = 0) and get the following dimension array.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 2
    )
   [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 1
    )
)
Array
(
    [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
    )
)
Array
(
    [4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 1
    )
    [5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 3
    )
    [6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 2
    )
)
Array
(
    [7] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 2
    )
    [8] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 1
    )
 )
```

I have spent hours to figure this out but due to less experience I still cannot get this done. Please help me with some algoritme.

Comment: Please show the code that built the original array

Answer (score 3):

Won't that do the trick?

```
$result = [];
foreach ($originalArrays as $array) {
  $result[$array[0]][] = $array;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be: `$result[$array[0]][] = $array;`?

Comment: Sorry, fixed the typo :) Thanks :)